# Retrieve information from google search console using Search Console APIs in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, google-analytics, google-search-console

I am successfully able to retrieve details from Google Analytics Reporting API, but when I am trying to access website(property) details from Google Search console using Search Console APIs in C#, it doesn't retrieve any information. Basically i need to fetch list of sites(user's Search Console sites) and visitors per keyword. 
I am using [Google Webmaster Tool APIs](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools) Search Console API v3. In APIs Expolorer it retrieves list of sites(webmasters.sites.list). When I am trying to implement same method in C# console application it doesn't fetch any data. Please check below code and attached image.

```
 GoogleCredential credentials;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string[] scopes = {
                //AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics, // view and manage your Google Analytics data
                //AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsEdit, // Edit and manage Google Analytics Account
                //AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsManageUsers, // Edit and manage Google Analytics Users
                //AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly,
                 //AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.Analytics,
                WebmastersService.Scope.WebmastersReadonly,
                WebmastersService.Scope.Webmasters
           };

            var googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
            credentials = googleCredential.CreateScoped(scopes);

        }

 WebmastersService service1 = new WebmastersService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credentials
        });

        SitesResource.ListRequest res = service1.Sites.List();
        var sites = res.Execute();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this issue resolved by adding google "service account" with full rights in to google search console for selected property. Here are the steps.

1. Logged in with admin account in google
2. Go to search console site (https://search.google.com/u/0/search-console)
3. Select the property "https://www.----.com" in the top left corner
4. "Settings" in the menu on the left-hand side
5. "Users and rights"
6. Top right "Add user"
7. Added our google "SERVICE account" with full rights.

[image]